# Add persistent state store to kafka consumer in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Currently, I have a simple setup with a kafka producer and a kafka consumer, connected with a topic. On restart, the consumer reads all events from the topic from offset 0 to build an in memory cache out of this data.

As this puts a very high dependency and load on kafka, I would like to extend the consumer by a local, persistent state store which can be used to initialize the consumer instead of replaying all events. As far as I understand, the approach with kafka would be to have a streams application (service) between the topic and the consumer, which puts the events into a state store.

I'm unsure what's next. Can the consumer be connected only to the state store and use it as a kind of stream, i.e. initialize from it and afterward listen to it as it now does listen to events? Or should/can the consumer somehow initialize from the state store, but then listen to the topic to receive events which were not yet persisted in the state store?

I'm interested both in the architectural design and in code examples using the spring boot kafka integration, as this seems to be quite an unusual use case, and I wasn't able to find examples explaining it.